# Почему правила именования BEM не использует теги и атрибуты?

Tags: css, бэм

Как известно, BEM состоит из блоков, элементов и модификаторов.

**Возьмем блоки.** Их предлагают отмечать отдельным классом.

```
<div class="x-block> Всякий дизайн </div>
```

Но блок, это по сути компонент, его можно и нужно задавать отдельным HTML элементом, как это уже давно реализовано во всяческих Angular и React.

```
<x-block> Всякий дизайн </x-block>
```

**С элементами ничего интересного.**

```
<x-block>
   <x-block_element1> Текст </x-block_element1>
   <x-block_element2> Еще текст </x-block_element2>
</x-block>
```

**Но настоящая радость приходит с модификаторами!** Ведь это ничто иное, как аргументы. Вместо безумных классовых конструкций.

```
<x-block>
  <!-- Для boolean модификаторов -->
  <x-block_element1 mod1>Всякие дизайны</x-block_element1>
  <!-- Для модификаторов со значением -->
  <x-block_element2 mod2="value">Крайне разнообразные</x-block_element2>
</x-block>
```

**Чем плох этот подход? Почему его не применяют?** Мне кажется BEM идеально соответствует идеям обыкновенных тегов. Возможно я чего-то не знаю? Может быть возникают какие-то проблемы с селекторами?

Comment: О, классно. Метка бэм.

Answer (score 3):

Всё просто: **совместимость**. С ней пока всё очень ненадёжно, Custom Elements Specification всё ещё в статусе **working draft**, и браузерами поддерживается [*очень плохо*](http://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elements).

А до тех пор, пока этот стандарт не примут, HTML5, по сути, специфицирует **белый список** валидных элементов, вылезти за него значит нарушить стандарт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

React лишь инкапсулирует конструкции из "примитивных элементов" (которые в HTML5 специфицированы) и позволяет составлять из них более сложные HTML-подобным языком разметки (JSX).

Теоретически, для БЭМ такой препроцессор сделать тоже можно, и я не удивлюсь, если он всё же существует, просто малоизвестен.

**UPD:** *есть такой, [`posthtml`](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml), как сообщает [@Guria](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177434/guria), и в той же организации есть полифилл `posthtml-custom-elements`.*

Comment: https://events.yandex.ru/lib/talks/2132/

Comment: Custom Elements чуть больше, чем вообще не об этом. Они нужны для определения тегов с новым поведением описанном на JS - как в Angular и React.

Comment: @uhbif19 нарушение HTML5 в том, какие теги могут быть в контексте каких, всего-то. Это невалидная разметка. Она **может** работать, просто это не стандартизировано, а посему стабильным считать нельзя.

Comment: @D-side Что значит "какие теги могут быть в контексте каких"?

Comment: @uhbif19 скормите [эту разметку](http://pastebin.com/TsDgeRRC) [валидатору HTML5](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input), посмотрите на его реакцию.

Comment: @Nofate сам React тоже годится, безусловно %)

Comment: @D-side Да. Хорошо, я понял вашу позицию. На мой взгляд валидность совершенно не важна.

Comment: @uhbif19 разумеется, если вы разрабатываете что-то, что будет запускаться на ограниченном числе реализаций, в качестве "reference implementation" вы можете взять только их и проверять работоспособность только на них. Как в случае с Electron, где достаточно совместимости с Chromium. Просто не удивляйтесь, если какой-нибудь Firefox внезапно начнёт показывать белый экран вместо сайта. Он имеет на то полное право.

Comment: > Теоретически, для БЭМ такой препроцессор сделать тоже можно, и я не удивлюсь, если он всё же существует, просто малоизвестен. См
https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-custom-elements

Comment: @Guria ЧТД :) Добавил, спасибо.

Comment: @D-side Это даже не смешно. Использование невалидного HTML распространенная практика в веб разработке. То, что файрфокс имеет на что-то право, никак не повлияет на то, что он никогда не сломает совместимость.

Comment: @uhbif19 совместимость с чем? С тем, что не имеет письменно изложенного определения, только расплывчатое представление в голове разработчика? Да запросто.

Answer (score 2):

БЭМ в том числе ориентировался на максимизацию производительности. Один класс - это очень быстро. Один тег - тоже. А вот атрибуты - это уже гораздо медленее.

А так, по самой идеологии проблем не вижу.

Ещё по поводу валидности разметки - кастомные теги [должны содержать дефис](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/450102/178988).

Comment: Да, это да. Не знаю, почему не написал.